# How to highlight the selected row and header of handsontable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, handsontable

As a requirement I want to highlight the row and column header of a selected cell in handsontable, basically I want to change the background color of the corresponding header on click of a cell.

Handsontable has built in property which highlights the whole row on click of a cell

```
var
    data = [
      ['', 'Kia', 'Nissan', 'Toyota', 'Honda'],
      ['2013', 10, 11, 12, 13],
      ['2014', 20, 11, 14, 13],
      ['2015', 30, 15, 12, 13]
    ],
    container = document.getElementById('example1'),
    hot;

  hot = Handsontable(container, {
    data: data,
    minRows: 5,
    minCols: 6,
    currentRowClassName: 'currentRow',
    currentColClassName: 'currentCol',
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: true
  });

  hot.selectCell(2,2);
```

But I just want to highlight the headers by changing its background color, is there any way to achieve it using custom renderer?

Comment: I have created something similar kindly refer https://jsfiddle.net/0xg33f1f/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing the CSS Code in your example from `.highlight { … }` to `th.highlight { … }` should do the trick. At the end table headers in Handsontable are just  elements.

Answer (score 1):

Along with the code just some css.

```
.handsontable td.currentRow, .handsontable td.current {
    background: #f8f9f9;
}
```

Credit goes to this [solution](https://github.com/handsontable/docs-archive/issues/42#issuecomment-271283150).